# For how many types of x86-processors do Ngen and .net-native create native code at once?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, native, ngen

As long as there's .net installed - I understand that the IL code just lets .net take care of the different types of CPU's. But when we consider native code - as far as I understand (and please correct me if I'm wrong) - the code has to be compiled for every processor type independently, and a "CPU dispatcher" at the beginning of the executable chooses which code will be executed - dependent on the *exact* type of CPU. So there will be some "simplest" code that will run on *any* Intel/AMD CPU and there will then be some more optimized codes.

Hence my question: how many versions of the code will be created by .net-native, and how many by Ngen? Will Ngen have only one version, and not even the "simplest" one? Or will it also have that - so that if copied onto a different machine - it'll still work? Will .net-native have many versions - making the executable several times the size it could be? Or is most of the code the same, and only the optimizable parts written for whatever they could be optimized for?

**EDIT**

When I mention "type of processor" - I don't mean: X86 or ARM. I mean: ***within*** x86 (or x64). Such as processors supporting MMX, 3DNow!, SSE ...

Comment: This feature you guess exist does not in fact exist.  Today, it might be different tomorrow.  This is a strongly undocumented implementation detail, you can't ask questions about it since the answer will always be wrong.  Some day in 2015, by the looks of it.

Comment: @HansPassant The _feature_ you're referring to is multiple-native-codes? In both Ngen and .net-native? If so - I presume the former is very CPU-specific while the latter, to the contrary - uses only the universal set of instructions. Correct? [This information would be helpful - it would mean that .net-natived code won't choke on old client machines.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both NGEN and .NET Native generate a single set of code per architecture. They don't change code generation behavior based on the model of the user's processor.

In NGEN's case, this might change. A future version of NGEN could detect the processor model, since it's running on the end user's machine, and generate the best code for that model.

.NET Native works like C++. All code is generated in advance, not on the user's machine, and therefore the code needs to run on every supported processor model. .NET Native only runs on Win8.1 and above. So, the minimum system requirements for Win8.1 define the processor features available to .NET Native. For x86, Win8+ requires SSE2 to be available.

One interesting sidenote about MSVCRT:

.NET uses the Microsoft Visual C++ runtime for a number of utility functions. Some of the functions inside the C++ runtime *do* check for processor features and execute different code paths for different processors. (In particular, I know x86 memcpy does this.) These checks happen at runtime, and the code remains portable across different processor models.

Comment: Thanks. I was about to ask for some kind of source, until I read your profile. :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: **exactly one**.

NGen will compile the IL code into the native code of your platform. You're not supposed to move the exe file between machines, as it's registered in the GAC for your own machine, and linked against its NGen'd dependencies. The native image generation is performed on the target machine.

As for .NET native, the exe will contain only the native code for one architecture, just like a classic compiler would do. If you need to support different architectures, you'll end up with several exe files, unless you make some packing mechanism of your own, but that would kind of defeat the purpose of .NET native.

Right now, .NET native is supported on [x64 and ARM only](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn600165.aspx).

Comment: Oh I see... Well, the NGen part of my answer still stands, but I'm not sure about .NET native. Also, I don't know if NGen supports SIMD code generation (the JIT support is brand new and requires RyuJIT - the next x64 JIT version)